# yfinance "history" function not working with python

Tags: python

Im trying to run a simple history function on certain dates and keep getting the error
"    df.index = df.index.tz_localize("UTC").tz_convert(
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'   "

here is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
aapl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
hist = aapl.history(start='2022-01-10', end='2022-01-20')
```

Comment: I was able to confirm the same phenomenon. It seems the cause is due to pandas 1.4.0 and I need to revert to 1.3.5. For more [details](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/937), please refer to here. I'll downgrade mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and I'd found the solution in https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/937.

I had to make changes to the utils.py file for it to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).